# Tool to convert xsd to c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, serialization, xsd, xml-parsing

Is there any tool to convert xsd to c++ code. The generated code can be used for serialization and parsing the xml. It should also be run as a independent.
I saw some opensource tools like *CodeSynthesis* but it has covered by GPL license.
I am looking for a tool which will generate code that could run independently.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx can convert to C#, maybe that helps, I don't know how set you are on making it C++ code.

Comment: _xsd.exe some.xsd /l:CPP /c_  will help.

Comment: Is xsd.exe can really use for C++??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) generates code for C++\CLI too.
It is not added in *\languages* in the documentation. But when executing xsd.exe in VS CommandPrompt, in the *\languages* section you could see CPP.
Generate the cpp code using the following command : *xsd.exe some.xsd /l:CPP /c*

Comment: I didn't know that, because I had only used it for C# and it really didn't show in the documentation. Good catch!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in newer versions of Visual Studio (2017 or 2019). I get the error: `Error: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider, CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located.`