# xsd.exe does not seem to work for C++ with newer versions of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, xsd, xsd.exe

I am trying to use the `xsd.exe` tool to generate C++ classes from XML schema files. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743475/tool-to-convert-xsd-to-c-code) I should simply be able to use the tool from a Visual Studio developer command prompt, but it doesn't seem to work for C++ in newer versions of Visual Studio (2017 or 2019)

When I try to execute the command I get the error:

> Error: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider, CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located.

There doesn't seem to be any information on this in the documentation and a Google search was no help... Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does it happen for just `xsd /?`? If not please post the command line and input file(s).

Comment: I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft Develper Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html). Also, I suggset that you could use [xsd2cc](https://github.com/yibit/xsd2cc), which could convert a .xsd file to C++ classes

Comment: @dxiv, no it works for just showing help, and it also works for generating C# classes. It just fails when I specify `/language:CPP`

Comment: @BarrnetChou thanks, I'll checkout `xsd2cc`! From a quick glance it's not clear if it will work on Windows though (I am developing in a Windows environment). I'll also submit a ticket to Microsoft directly since `xsd.exe` definitely seems broken.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 A simple export/import test works for me with VS 2019 16.7.5. Could be because I also have VS 2015 installed, however, see Microsoft's resolution on [CppCodeProvider not properly installed with VS2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/240322/cppcodeprovider-not-properly-installed-with-vs2017.html): "*project support for xsd.exe is deprecated. You can still use the Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider APIs by manually adding CppCodeProvider.dll to the GAC*".

Comment: Thanks @dxiv, I did not realize it was deprecated! If it is deprecated I will try to avoid using it and look for an alternative.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Not sure what "*deprecated*" literally means. Another comment there, also from MS, says that "*in VS 2017 CppCodeProvider.dll is getting shipped with 'Desktop development with C++'*". I have `CppCodeProvider.dll` in `Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` under each of VS 2015, 2017 and 2019 on my machine.

Comment: @dxiv, Yes I have the `dll` as well, but even if I copy it and drop it in the same directory I run `xsd` from it doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 They say you need to add it to the GAC. Anyway, found the official statement [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/xsd-task?view=vs-2019): "*Starting in Visual Studio 2017, C++ project support for xsd.exe is deprecated. You can still use the Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider APIs by manually adding CppCodeProvider.dll to the GAC.*".

Comment: @dxiv, excuse my ignorance, but I've never heard of the GAC before. What exactly is the GAC and how do I add a DLL to it? The linked page only says that you need to add it to the GAC but it doesn't specify how.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 See [How to: Install an assembly into the global assembly cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac), in particular `gacutil`.

Comment: @dxiv That looks like what I need. Thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xsd.exe` was deprecated in VS 2017, with a note under [XSD Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/xsd-task?view=vs-2019) reading:

> Starting in Visual Studio 2017, C++ project support for `xsd.exe` is deprecated. You can still use the Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider APIs by manually adding CppCodeProvider.dll to the GAC.

This was confirmed in Microsoft sanctioned comments under the related ticket [CppCodeProvider not properly installed with VS2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/240322/cppcodeprovider-not-properly-installed-with-vs2017.html), which was closed as "*by design*".

The `CppCodeProvider.dll` assembly, however, continued to be released with the "*Desktop development with C++*" workload, and can still be found under the `Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` directory in VS 2017 and 2019. The assembly can be added to the GAC using the global assembly cache tool [`gacutil`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac) at a VS developer command prompt.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Don't know about that one. Just ran a quick test and generated a schema with `xsd sample.dll` then created a header with `xsd /c /l:cpp schema0.xsd`. That "worked" without any reported errors and built in fact a C++ .h file, though it's missing most of the public types in the assembly. Not sure whether/how that's even supposed to work in a useful way.

Comment: It looks like it generates C++/CLI code which is basically a Microsoft extension of the C++ language that only works with Windows.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Right, that's C++/CLI for sure. But it looks like a partial "conversion" at best. The assembly I used for the quick test was written in C++/CLI as well, but it had several nested classes and APIs which didn't make it into the generated schema, and obviously not into the converted header, either.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to find another tool... Either that or try to hack one together myself (maybe with Perl) but that would be quite a bit of effort. I guess I'll check out `xsd2cc` as was mentioned in previous comments first.